# bind onerror with dynamically created image tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, src, onerror

i am trying to bind the onerror of img with a function. image tag is created like this in jquery

```
this._img1 = $("<img>");
```

this is the function

```
function imgError(image) {
  image.onerror = "";
  image.src = '/Content/img/placeholder-profile.jpg';
  return true;
}
```

now i want to bind this function with onerror ...
i've tried following things and they wont work for me

```
this._img1.on("onError", "imgError(" + this._img1 + ")");
```

and

```
this._img1.prop("onError", "imgError(this)");
```

and

```
this._img1.error(function () {
    _img1.src = '/Content/img/placeholder-profile.jpg';
});
```

can anyone suggest me how can i achieve it ?

Comment: What is `this._img1`? I guess it is a DOM node element, not jq object. So you have to wrap it in jq object to use jq method on it: `$(this._img1).on('error', function(){_img1.src = '/Content/img/placeholder-profile.jpg';});`. Or use native js method to bind event

Comment: @A. Wolff
'this' is the main div element in which all other elements are wrapped and in which we are displaying the results. It is the jquery widget call actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in my own case, I simply registered a global listener for the `onError` event like so:

```
$("img").on('error', function() {
  $(this).attr("src", "/path/to/my/default/placeholder-image.png");
});
```

This took care of all broken image links. In your case, you can use either/both `#id` and/or `.class` selectors to narrow down to specific elements.

The jquery `.on()` function works for dynamically created elements, too. See sample [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp)

Comment: this works only for the elements already in the DOM when the jQuery code is executed. if any elements are added later, the handler will not be attached.

Comment: Does not work for dynamically added images.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this functioning simply use .error() of jquery. Bind an event handler to the "error" JavaScript event.

```
Type: Function( Event eventObject )
```

A function to execute when the event is triggered.

The error event is sent to elements, such as images, that are referenced by a document and loaded by the browser. It is called if the element was not loaded correctly.

For example, consider a page with a simple image element:

```
<img alt="Book" id="book">
```

The event handler can be bound to the image:

```
$( "#book" )
  .error(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .error() called." )
  })
  .attr( "src", "missing.png" );
```

If the image cannot be loaded (for example, because it is not present at the supplied URL), the alert is displayed:

Handler for .error() called.

Comment: ive tried that too as you can see that in my question but it wont work .... dont know why :(

Comment: while you create a img tag then also create its id with it . Then you will be able to access it.

Comment: Please show me your console error and your current on JSfiddle  Thanks